# aaptOptions don't make effort for 'com.android.library' project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Include the following information that is specific for problems related to building your projects or problems with Gradle sync:
Gradle version:
4.1
Android Plugin Version: 
3.0.1
Module Compile Sdk Version: 
26
Module Build Tools Version: 
26.0.2
Android SDK Tools version: 
28.0.1

in my project,i want to build an aar and my script like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters  '-I', project.bundleDir+'/resource/package-export.apk',
           ...
    }
....
```

in the pacage-export.apk i extend resource of android.jar and use package name 'androidext',but i get many errors "No resource identifier found for attribute 'shape_mode' in package 'androidext'" on the task 
verifyReleaseResource, and I found the aapt command of the verifyReleaseResource task don't include aaptOptions.additionalParmeters in my config,so how can i build library porject when i extend resources of android.jar?